# How to create Parent and Child records using Lightning Edit Form in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-record-form

I have a requirement where user should be able to create Parent and child record with single button click on one page.
For this I created 2 lightning-record-edit-form on the LWC, but unable to find a way to pass the Parent Id to Child record form on submit. Can any one suggest some ideas on how to acheive it?
In the below picture first 2 fields come from Parent and second 2 from child.
On save both records should be saved, Child should be related to the Parent.
I am using 2 forms because, child fields might vary based on the record type of parent.

**LWC**:

```
<template>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <br />
            <lightning-card>
                <lightning-record-edit-form
                    record-id={recordId}
                    object-api-name="ParentObject__c"
                    record-type-id={parentId}
                    onsuccess={handleSuccess}
                    onsubmit={handleSubmit}
                    onerror={handleError}
                                        >
                    <lightning-messages> </lightning-messages>
                    
                    <template>
                        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                            <!-- <template if:true={fields}>-->
                            <template for:each={parentfields} for:item="f">
                                <div key={f.Id} class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                                    <lightning-input-field field-name={f.APIName}> </lightning-input-field>
                                </div>
                            </template>
                            <!--</template>-->
                        </div>
                    </template>
                </lightning-record-edit-form></lightning-card
            >
            <template>
                <template>
                    <lightning-card title="Account/Site-Specific Fields">
                        <lightning-record-edit-form
                            record-id={recordId}
                            object-api-name="childObject__c"
                            onsuccess={handleSuccess}
                            onsubmit={handleSubmit}
                            onerror={handleError}
                        >
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                                <!-- <template if:true={fields}>-->
                                <template for:each={childfields} for:item="f">
                                    <div key={f.Id} class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                                        <lightning-input-field field-name={f.APIName}> </lightning-input-field>
                                    </div>
                                </template>
                                <!--</template>-->
                            </div>
                        </lightning-record-edit-form></lightning-card
                    ></template
                >
            </template>


            <br />
        </div>
        <div slot="footer">
            <template>
            <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small slds-p-right_medium" variant="brand" onclick={handleSubmit} name="save" label="Save"> </lightning-button
            ></template>
        </div>
    
</template>
```

**JS:**

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
import CreationChild from '@salesforce/apex/CreationController.CreationChild';
import getForm from '@salesforce/apex/CreationController.getForm';
import getRecordTypeId from '@salesforce/apex/CreationController.getRecordTypeId';
import getRecordTypeDevName from '@salesforce/apex/CreationController.getRecordTypeDevName';
import { RefreshEvent } from 'lightning/refresh';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
export default class CreationLwc extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    DisplayText = false;
    @api size;
    @api objectName;
    @api recordId;
    @api fieldSet;
    @track fields;
    @track systemfields;
    @track isModalOpen = false;
    @api PortfolioRecordTypeName;
    @api PortfolioRecordTypeId;
    @api PortfolioRecordTypeDevName = 'Test';
    @api accrecordId;
    @api showOFields = false;
    @api showTFields = false;
    @api portAccountId;
    @api selectedPortfolioId;
    @api showPortfolio = false;
    isLoading = false;
    @api isSystemFields = false;
    account;
    

    openModal() {
        this.isModalOpen = true;
    }
    closeModal() {
        this.isModalOpen = false;
        this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent());
    }
    submitDetails() {
        this.isModalOpen = false;
    }
    handleSuccess(event) {
        console.log('onsubmit event recordEditForm' + event.detail.id);
                this.createRelationship( event.detail.id, this.accrecordId, 'Owner');
                this.navigateToRecordPage();
    }
   
    handleOTChange(event) {
        console.log('You selected an account: ' + event.detail.value);
        if (event.detail.value === 'Owner') {
                        this.getFieldsForOwner();
                        this.getFieldsForChild();
            this.showOFields = true;
            this.showTFields = false;
            this.showPortfolio = false;
            //this.connectedCallback();
        } 
        } else if (event.detail.value === '') {
            this.showOFields = false;
            this.showTFields = false;
        }
    }
    
    getFieldsForOwner() {
        //this.template.querySelector('c-modal').show();
        getForm({ recordId: this.recordId, objectName: 'parent__c', fieldSetName: this.PortfolioRecordTypeDevName })
            .then(result => {
                console.log('Data:' + JSON.stringify(result));
                if (result) {
                    this.fields = result.Fields;
                    this.error = undefined;
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.error = error;
            });
    }
    
    validateFields() {
        return [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field')].reduce((validSoFar, field) => {
            return validSoFar && field.reportValidity();
        }, true);
    }
  
        handleSubmit(e){
        
                const inputFields = e.detail.fields;
                this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(inputFields);  
        
        
        }
    handleError(e) {
        //this.template.querySelector('[data-id="message"]').setError(e.detail.detail);
        e.preventDefault();
    }

       
    closeComponent() {
        const close = new CustomEvent('close');
        this.dispatchEvent(close);
    }
        navigateToRecordPage() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: "standard__recordPage",
            attributes: {
              actionName: "view",
              recordId: this.accrecordId
            }
          });
}
         handleEmpty(event) {
        this.account = event.detail;
    }
         getFieldsForChild() {
        
        getForm({ recordId: this.recordId, objectName: 'child__c', fieldSetName: this.PortfolioRecordTypeDevName })
            .then(result => {
                console.log('Data:system fields' + JSON.stringify(result));
                if (result) {
                    this.systemfields = result.Fields;
                                        this.isSystemFields = true;
                    this.error = undefined;
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.error = error;
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your javascript code as well, would like to see the event handler methods

Comment: @prem22 added js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add an identifier on both form, e.g. `data-id="parent"` and `data-id="child"`, in order to query the right one.
Moreover I would remove `onsubmit={handleSubmit}` on both form since they are not being called. What runs is the one on the Save button, therefore you can change the `handleSubmit` code to:

```js
handleSubmit() {
    this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form[data-id="parent"]').submit();
}
```

I would import the lookup field to use it later:

```js
import LOOKUP_TO_PARENT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/ChildObject__c.Parent__c';
```

I would also have two differents handlers for the `onsuccess` event, e.g. `onsuccess={handleSuccessParent}` and `onsuccess={handleSuccessChild}`.
In `handleSuccessParent` method you should store the id of the parent object, the build the object with every child field, in order to pass it to the `submit` method.
Since you didn't add the `createRelationship` method to the question, I'm going to assume that `accrecordId` holds the Id of the parent record.

```js
handleSuccessParent(event) {
    const parentId = event.detail.id;
    this.accrecordId = parentId;
    const inputFields = {};
    inputFields[LOOKUP_TO_PARENT_FIELD.fieldApiName] = parentId;
    const childInputFields = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-record-edit-form[data-id="child"] lightning-input-field');
    for (const field of childInputFields) {
        if (field.value) {
            inputFields[field.fieldName] = field.value;
        }
    }
    console.log('inputFields', inputFields);
    this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form[data-id="child"]').submit(inputFields);
}
```

In `handleSuccessParent` method you could navigate to the record page as you did in your `handleSuccess` method:

```js
handleSuccessChild() {
    this.navigateToRecordPage();
}
```

The HTML should look like:

```html
<template>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <br />

        <lightning-card>
            <lightning-record-edit-form
                record-id={recordId}
                object-api-name="ParentObject__c"
                data-id="parent"
                record-type-id={parentId}
                onsuccess={handleSuccessParent}
                onerror={handleError}>
                <lightning-messages> </lightning-messages>
                
                <template>
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                        <!-- <template if:true={fields}>-->
                        <template for:each={parentfields} for:item="f">
                            <div key={f.Id} class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                                <lightning-input-field field-name={f.APIName}> </lightning-input-field>
                            </div>
                        </template>
                        <!--</template>-->
                    </div>
                </template>
            </lightning-record-edit-form>
        </lightning-card>

        <template>
            <lightning-card title="Account/Site-Specific Fields">
                <lightning-record-edit-form
                    record-id={recordId}
                    object-api-name="childObject__c"
                    data-id="child"
                    onsuccess={handleSuccessChild}
                    onerror={handleError}>
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                        <!-- <template if:true={fields}>-->
                        <template for:each={childfields} for:item="f">
                            <div key={f.Id} class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                                <lightning-input-field field-name={f.APIName}> </lightning-input-field>
                            </div>
                        </template>
                        <!--</template>-->
                    </div>
                </lightning-record-edit-form>
            </lightning-card>
        </template>

        <br/>
    </div>

    <div slot="footer">
        <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small slds-p-right_medium" variant="brand" onclick={handleSubmit} name="save" label="Save"> </lightning-button>
    </div>

</template>
```